# Why the character ';' is added the end of request in OAuth2

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, microservices, spring-security-oauth2

There are Authorization Server(UAA) and Resource Server and Gateway applications that have been working correctly. The scenario for authentication is `authorization_code`. In the first time after authentication, the end of request is added `;jesessionid=[value]`, so its result is exception from `HttpFirewall` of Gateway application, because of having `';'` in the request.
**My question is that what is it and why jessionid is added the end of request? and how is it adaptable with `HttpFirewall`.**

I have found a way around but I know it has some risks. It is like this:

```
@Bean
public HttpFirewall allowUrlEncodedSlashHttpFirwall() {
    StrictHttpFirewall firewall = new StrictHttpFirewall();
    firewall.setAllowSemicolon(true);
    return firewall;
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .headers().cacheControl().disable()
            .and()
            .headers()
            .cacheControl()
            .disable()
            .frameOptions()
            .sameOrigin()
            .and()
            .httpBasic().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint()).permitAll()
            .requestMatchers(PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations()).permitAll()
            .mvcMatchers("/uaa/**", "/login**", "/favicon.ico", "/error**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll();
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    super.configure(web);
    web.httpFirewall(allowUrlEncodedSlashHttpFirwall());
}
```

As above configuration, the `;` is skipped but it is not right and it has some risks.

What is the correct way and config to solve this problem?

Comment: In http config, try with:
`.and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
`
**“stateless” – is a guarantee that the application will not create any session at all.**

Comment: Would you explain more as answer of this question about stateless.

Comment: In the session-based approcah, a session id—which is a kind of server generated token—is generated and stored in a cookie within the JSESSIONID paramter. 
Oauth2 is implementing stateless authentication, no session will be created or used by Spring Security.

Comment: Do I config the stateless in the Gateway application?

Comment: As your explain about stateless, If I change to stateless, how the OAuth2 manages the authenticated requests?

Comment: References in [here](https://github.com/xetys/jhipster-uaa-setup/blob/1615a37912afc927a55dd8156672fea1cd8d21c1/uaa/src/main/java/com/mycompany/myapp/config/UaaConfiguration.java#L52).

OAuth2 using Token Approach.

Comment: I have configed the UAA as your answer, but the redirection url does not work after authentication and redirect to index.html of UAA instead of redirect to my callback url